# Phaser and PhaserJS tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

I'm not sure if it's the right place for this kind of post but i just notice that the `phaser` tag don't reference to the young `javascript` game engine framework `phaserjs` but to a `java class`. Or people starts to use it for javascript issues. i'm wondering if maybe someone (who can do it) could create a seperate tag for the `javascript framework` and retag some posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I retagged all of the questions related to the Phaser game development framework to [phaser-framework](/questions/tagged/phaser-framework). I thought this was a better fit than [phaser-js](/questions/tagged/phaser-js) since the Phaser web site doesn't call it “Phaser JS”, instead opting to call it Phaser each time. I'm also considering retagging all the remaining [phaser](/questions/tagged/phaser) questions to [java-phaser](/questions/tagged/java-phaser) to further disambiguate.